# How can I check which tab is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a problem I have some tabs and I would like to know which tab is active on my website ?

In the javascript console I noticed when I writing this `$('#id1');` in the console of the browser I got :

```
n.fn.init [div#id1.tab-pane.active, context: document, selector: "#id1"]
0: div#id1.tab-pane.active
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#id1"
__proto__: Object(0)
```

When the tab is not active I got this when I writing this in the console `$('#id1');` :

```
n.fn.init [div#id1.tab-pane, context: document, selector: "#id1"]
0: div#id1.tab-pane
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#id1"
__proto__: Object(0)
```

Do you know what I have to write to have a boolean when the tab is active or not ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: From the output of the console you can tell if the tab is active from the `.active` class on it. If you need more specific help, please add your code to the question.

Comment: I type that : `$('#id1').active;`but I got `undefined`

Comment: That's not a valid selector. `$('#id1.active')` would be. However, it depends on how your JS is structured as to how you need to check the element has the class. You may need `hasClass('active')` instead, however as you've not shown any of the relevant code we can't really help you effectively